# Pointwise convergence of this sequence $f_n: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

> **Problem** Let the following sequence $f_n: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
> $$ f_n(x) = \sum\limits^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +k^x}}$$
> Show that $f_n$ converges to a function $f$ such that:
>
> a) $\;f(2)=\ln(1+\sqrt2)$
>
> b)$\;f(x)=1 \quad x\in[0,2)$
>
> c)$\;f(x)=0 \quad x>2$

I'm out of ideas with this problem. What sort of trick I can use to deal of this sequence ?

Comment: Is there a typo? As written $f_n$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: Sorry. Now is correct with $k^x$

Comment: I feel like at least for the first one or two you can do some Riemann sum magic to convert into an integral but I might be mistaken.

Comment: The first one I've tried was to show $ \rvert{ f_n - \ln(1+\sqrt 2) } \rvert \rightarrow 0 $ (something like that) but I didnt get anywhere. b) and c) I have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, by Riemann sum approximation $$ f_n(2) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \big(\frac{k}{n}\big)^2}} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx $$
and you need to evaluate that integral (For example by trigonometric/hiperbolic substitution)

Now, if $x \in [0,2)$ then $x-2 <0$ so that $n^{x-2} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$ $$1 = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}} \le f_n(x) \le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n^x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ n^{x-2}}} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}1$$
Similarly with the last one, for $x > 2$ you have $x-2>0$ so that $n^{x-2} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \infty$ and $$ 0 \le f_n(x) \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n^x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^{x-2}}} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$$

Comment: The first one has a pretty nice trick. Thank you for your help!